# Private key in pem file: what is the purpose to keep it clear?

Tags: tls1.2

I am not sure I understand why the private key can be keep in clear and not encrypted in a pem file, if it is not encrypted is a security vulnerability? If it is in clear, are there other mechanism to protect the pem file itself?

Thanks

Comment: Classic problem: see https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart

Comment: ok, still, are u saying that if the key is not in clear should rotate to enhance security, otherwise we need to encrypt it?

Comment: Most pragmatic approach is to set file permissions on the key as rigid as possible, so that only the webserver process owner can read it. Eventually depends on your security policy...

Comment: ah, I see, thanks!